# json unmarshal generic interface{}

Tags: go

http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go

`m := j.(map[string]interface{})` didn't work for me

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not map[string]interface {}
```

So I end up with code like this to make it work? Don't think its the correct way of doing it :)

```
    var j interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &j)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
    }

    m := j.([]interface{}) //map[string]interface{}

    for k, v := range m {
        switch vv := v.(type) {
        case string:
            fmt.Println(k, "is string", vv)
        case int:
            fmt.Println(k, "is int", vv)
        case []interface{}:
            fmt.Println(k, "is an array:")
            for i, u := range vv {
                fmt.Println(i, u)
            }
        case map[string]interface{}:
            for k2, v2 := range v.(map[string]interface{}) {
                switch vv2 := v2.(type) {
                case string:
                    fmt.Println(k2, "is string", vv2)
                case int:
                    fmt.Println(k2, "is int", vv2)
                case []interface{}:
                    fmt.Println(k2, "is an array:")
                    for i2, u2 := range vv2 {
                        fmt.Println(i2, u2)
                    }
                default:
                    fmt.Println(k2, "is of a type I don't know how to handle")
                }
            }
        default:
            fmt.Println(k, "is of a type I don't know how to handle")
        }
    }
```

EDIT: My failed attempt to make it readable

```
    var j interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &j)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
    }
    write(j.([]interface{}))

func write(j []interface{}) {
    for k, v := range j {
        switch vv := v.(type) {
        case string:
            fmt.Println(k, "is string", vv)
        case int:
            fmt.Println(k, "is int", vv)
        case []interface{}:
            fmt.Println(k, "is an array:")
            for i, u := range vv {
                fmt.Println(i, u)
            }
        case map[string]interface{}:
            write(v.([]interface{}))
        default:
            fmt.Println(k, "is of a type I don't know how to handle")
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT2: Works but still ugly

```
    var j interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &j)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
    }
    write(j.([]interface{}))

func write(j []interface{}) {
    for k, v := range j {
        switch vv := v.(type) {
        case string:
            fmt.Println(k, "is string", vv)
        case int:
            fmt.Println(k, "is int", vv)
        case []interface{}:
            fmt.Println(k, "is an array:")
            for i, u := range vv {
                fmt.Println(i, u)
            }
        case map[string]interface{}:
            write2(v.(map[string]interface{}))
        default:
            fmt.Println(k, "is of a type I don't know how to handle")
        }
    }
}

func write2(j map[string]interface{}) {
    for k, v := range j {
        switch vv := v.(type) {
        case string:
            fmt.Println(k, "is string", vv)
        case int:
            fmt.Println(k, "is int", vv)
        case []interface{}:
            fmt.Println(k, "is an array:")
            for i, u := range vv {
                fmt.Println(i, u)
            }
        default:
            fmt.Println(k, "is of a type I don't know how to handle")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your data have no predefined structure? Yes, this is what you have to do if you don't know the data structures are (though there's better ways of structuring the code)

Comment: Exactly, it doesn't have a structure. How can I make the above code more readable please?

Comment: Do you want to print everything unmarshaled from JSON recursively or just the "top" layer?

Comment: Yes loop over everything and print it without shortcuts :P It's my blueprint for when I need to play with the data later on, thanks. So I probably need to do something more recursive here.

Comment: You don't handle nested objects. Better make recursive calls as suggested above.

Comment: added my failed attempt to do so.

Comment: What's some of the sample JSON you're trying to decode? Is the initial structure an array of objects? Seems like you're type asserting into it fairly confident...

Comment: Correct, type asserting it to reduce complexity for now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as the root part of the JSON code is a JSON array (the `["item", "item", {"key": "value"}]` notation). Although some JSON libraries don't like it, the "root" of the JSON blob can be an array and not an object (the `{"key": "value"}` notation).

In a production application, you should use the second value of type assertions to make sure it's the right type:

```
m, mOk := j.(map[string]interface{})
s, sOk := j.([]interface{})

if mOk {
    // Use Map
} else {
    // Use Slice
}
```

If you don't need to edit the data, **[Jason](https://github.com/antonholmquist/jason)** is a great library for Go.